# Валидация вложенных в выбранный чекбокс полей

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте.
Есть форма, состоящая из ряда одинаковых блоков

```
<div class="progblock">
<div class="strelka"><a href=""><img src="/template/img/ico/strelka.png" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
<label class="bold_name"><input type="checkbox" name="public" 
class="public osnova" value="Программа 1"> Программа 1</label>

<div class="napravlenie hides" style="display:none;">
         <div class="checkbox col-xs-6 forma_obuchen">
             <select name="ot_forma1" class="form-control">
              <option value="">Форма обучения</option>
                <option value="Очно-заочная">Очно-заочная</option>
                <option value="Дистанционная">Дистанционная</option>
             </select>
         </div>
         <div class="checkbox col-xs-6 kolvo_uchenik">
         <input type="number" name="ot_kolvo1" value="" 
class="form-control" placeholder="Число слушателей">
         </div>
         </div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Есть скрипт, отвечающий за сбор данных с формы и передачу их на следующий шаг, а также за валидацию формы. У нас при выборе каких-либо чекбоксов происходит разворачивание скрытого блока под чекбоксом и там уже пользователь выбирает форму обучения и количество слушателей. Вот без выбранных этих двух полей дальнейший шаг - открытие модального окна выполняться не должен.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a.podtv').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var arr = [].map.call($('input:checkbox:checked'), function(el) {
    var parent = $(el).parents('.progblock');
    return {
      'name': el.value,
      'type': $('select', parent).val(),
      'val': $('[type="number"]', parent).val()
    }
  });
var mass = JSON.stringify(arr, null, 4);
// Блок валидации
var es = $('input:checkbox:checked')
var parents = $(es).parents('.progblock');
var selprogblock = $('select', parents).val();
var numprogblock = $('[type="number"]', parents).val();
// Проверяем выбрана ли форма обучения
if (selprogblock == '') {
  alert('Выберите форму обучения!');
}
// Проверяем выбрано ли количество слушателей
else if (numprogblock == '') {
  alert('Введите количество слушателей!');
} else {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    $(".info_users_prog").append('<p>' + arr[i].name + '</p><ul><li>' + arr[i].type + '</li><li>' + arr[i].val + '</li></ul>');
    $(".parameter").append('<input type="hidden" name="names[]" value="' + arr[i].name + '">');
    $(".parameter").append('<input type="hidden" name="types[]" value="' + arr[i].type + '">');
    $(".parameter").append('<input type="hidden" name="vals[]" value="' + arr[i].val + '">');
    $("#myModal").show("slow");
  }
}
});
  $('button.close').click(function(e) {
    $("#myModal").hide("slow");
    arr = [];
    $('.info_users_prog').empty();
  });
  $('button.closer').click(function(e) {
    $("#myModal").hide("slow");
    arr = [];
    $('.info_users_prog').empty();
    $('.parameter').empty();
  });
});
```

Но на практике форма состоит не из одного блока а из многих. И если хотя бы в одном из них данные по форме обучения и количеству слушателей выбраны, то на остальные валидация не реагирует и форма проходит валидацию.
Как сделать чтобы проверялись все поля у выбранных чекбоксов?

**UPD:** Пытаюсь сделать проверку таким образом, но в данном варианте вылезает сообщение alert, но скрипт продолжает исполняться далее. и в результате открывается модальное окно, в котором есть только те данные, поля которых заполнены правильно. Получается просто не добавляет те данные где сработала ошибка валидации. А как просто остановить дальнейшее исполнение скрипта, чтобы даже модалка не открывалась?

```
var arr= [].map.call($('input:checkbox:checked'),function(el) {
        var parent = $(el).parents('.progblock');
        if ($('select',parent).val() == '') {
    alert('Выберите форму обучения!');
    return;
        }
        else if ($('[type="number"]',parent).val() == '') {
    alert('Введите количество слушателей!');
    return;
        }
        else {
        return {
            'name' : el.value, 
            'type' : $('select',parent).val(), 
            'val' : $('[type="number"]',parent).val()
            }
        }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery validation plugin**

Вы можете использовать специальный плагин для проверки форм:

https://jqueryvalidation.org/

У него есть специальная функция `validate`, которая выполняет проверку формы без отправки ее на сервер: https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

Он поддерживает проверку `Select`, `Radio`:

https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/radio-checkbox-select-demo.html

Нужно только подключить библиотеку и добавить необходимые атрибуты в теги `select`, которые обязательны для заполнения.

Comment: У меня все это дело не в тегах <form>/ То есть фактически не форма а просто набор div'ов. Плагин будет работать?

Comment: Нет. Добавьте тег

Comment: А если у меня не форма а набор div'ов то как быть? Я могу добавить теги form но я так понимаю валидация через плагин работает по нажатию кнопки submit а у меня там просто ссылка.

Comment: @Batyabest Вы можете вызвать проверку формы с помощью javascript: `var validator = $( "#myform" ).validate();
validator.form();` https://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.form/